# Kafka-producer duplicate check

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

How can I verify duplication of messages in a particular topic?
I have producer which sends messages to topic and consumer consumes those messages. so I wnt to verify that the messages consumed by consumer are not duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Idempotent Producer` to avoid message duplication. [read here](https://www.cloudkarafka.com/blog/apache-kafka-idempotent-producer-avoiding-message-duplication.html#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20Idempotent%20Producer,either%20be%20resent%20or%20discarded.) for more information abouth Idempotent producer.

Comment: How will I find that the messages are getting duplicated? manually by looking at the messages in topic?

Comment: `Idempotent Producer`  does not publish duplicate messages. It makes sure `Exactly Ones` behaviour.